# LG K10 MT6753 boot partition deleted

Tags: unbricking, lg, mediatek

I have a little issue with my LG K10 K430. I was experimenting with it, to learn the `adb` function. Well, I stupidly erased the whole boot partition using `rm`, and then my phone is not booting anymore. It is showing the LG boot logo, but is not starting up, keeps rebooting.

I tried to:

1. Repair it through LG Bridge, to flash the stock ROM through LG UP and LG Flash Tool. But the phone is not staying in flash mode or download mode, cant boot into Fastboot. The only thing that apparently works is the Factory Reset mode, but only shows the interface. It only reboots the phone and nothing else.
2. Flash the boot image through SP Flash Tool but has no luck. The phone is detected by Windows but only for 3 seconds, then it disconnects. No matter what I do, when I connect the phone to my PC, it quickly disconnects, even with Driver Enforcement deactivated. I tried LG drivers and some other drivers for Mediatek, but still have no luck.

Is there any other way to recover the boot partition's data or to unbrick my phone?

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BoLawson the real location of that link (without Google Amp): https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/help/tutorial-fixing-fastboot-mode-started-t2995854/

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this video on backing up MTK Devices ( Mediatek ) prior to any system changes [MTK Backup & Restore](https://youtu.be/e2_U68EGSlY)

- Ok, you definitely need your CDC Drivers ( MTK Preloader Drivers )
  [MY Stock CDC & MTK Drivers](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17c43NusFkkVqhGYStPTytj3mHCqtMZYv/view?usp=drivesdk)
  Some drivers are .INF files, You need to right click and install ... These files are pulled from an MTK 6735 ROM   - CDC Drivers are usually universal for all MTK.
- And probably the newest SP Flash Tool ( V 5.16+ )

5.16 has new support, so get the newest version if you don't already have 5.16+

[SP Flash Tool 5.17.zip](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1lj4RfgSGkjns8M9g_yoQ0umpXh1HF_z9&export=download)

Ok, I'll need more information to completely resolve the problem.

How exactly did you remove boot with `RM` ...

And have you got a Boot Image For The Device....

I can help get everything working but please make sure you have the files above, and you need to watch the video ( English ) to understand how SP Flash Tool works ... Please do all these things and comment the answers ( the code you used to wipe ) etc....